# Copy by value in Angular not working properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build a simple editable div page where you can edit, cancel and save the contents. Clicking edit seems to enable the div for editing properly. However when I save, the value is not synchronized with what was entered. Additionally, when you cancel and need to revert back to what was there before, it does not pull the right value.

I have attempted to store the previous contents temporarily by concatenating the current value with and empty string to prevent copying a reference, but I'm failing to see where I'm messing up at.

I have created a simple example to demonstrate:
http://play.ionic.io/app/76fa89478b4c

Comment: Angular doesn't support `contenteditable` by itself. Search *"angular contenteditable"* for solutions. Also making all this more complicated than needed. Use objects and `angular.extend()` and `angular.copy()` to simplify

Answer (score 1):

It's because content editable is not working totally with angular.

replace your div with contenteditable by :

```
<input ng-model="contents" ng-disabled="!editingContents"/>
```

your html become like that :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestController">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding">
        <input ng-model="contents" ng-disabled="!editingContents"/>
        <br/>
        <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="edit()">edit</button>
        <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="cancel()">cancel</button>
        <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="save()">save</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As you eluded to, the ultimate issue ended up being with the way angular handled two-way binding contenteditable elements. Due to the way my application was written it was not desirable to use an input box. With the help of the following article, I wrote a custom directive to compensate for angular's lack of support: http://mehrantm.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-make-two-way-binding-to-your.html  which worked great for me.